# main() coming back as invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in a very basic intro level programming course and I'm learning functions. My code keeps returning the call to "main()" at the end of my program as a syntax error. Again I'm super bad at this so don't judge all of my mistakes

```
def main():
    speed = int(input('Enter the speed of the vehicle in mph: '))
    while speed < 0:
        print('Speed must be greater than zero')
        speed = int(input('Enter a valid speed: '))
    time = int(input('Enter the number of hours traveled: '))
    while time < 0:
        print('Time must be greater than zero')
        time = int(input('Enter a valid time: '))
    show_travel(speed,time)

def show_travel(speed,time):
    print('Hours\tDistance Traveled')
    print('----------------------------------------')
    for time in range(1, time + 1):
        distance = speed * time
        print(format(time, "d"), format(distance, "20.2f")
main()
```

when i run it it returns with main highlighted saying syntax error

Comment: Your `while speed < 0:` statements are indented one level to the right

Comment: looks like indentation issues...

Comment: where should they be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple parenthesis and indentation issues.  Try this code.  For the semantics, that is up to you.  But with my code, there are no errors thrown.

```
def main():
    speed = int(input('Enter the speed of the vehicle in mph: '))
    while speed < 0:
        print('Speed must be greater than zero')
        speed = int(input('Enter a valid speed: '))
    time = int(input('Enter the number of hours traveled: '))
    while time < 0:
        print('Time must be greater than zero')
        time = int(input('Enter a valid time: '))
        showtravel(speed,time)

def showtravel(speed,time):

    print('Hours\tDistance Traveled')
    print('----------------------------------------')
    for hours in range(1, hours + 1):
        distance = speed * time
        print(format(hours, "d"), format(distance, "20.2f"))
```

Comment: it says i have to wait a minute

Comment: You should be able to do it now.

Comment: all done. thanks again! saved my ass with 7 minutes til it was due